# Update multiple documents in Mongo that contain the same object?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So, I have multiple mongo docs that are "Groups". In each group I have a sub-object of an array of "Members". I am trying to do a query that to remove all instances of a "Member" from every "Group"?

Here's my Mongo doc structure

```
Group: {
  _id: whatever, 
  members: [
    {firstName: "stupid", lastName: "head"},
    {firstName: "stupid2", lastName: "head2"},
    {firstName: "stupid3", lastName: "head3"}
  ]
}
```

Say I have multiple of these "Groups". I wanna say "if a group contains 'stupid2 head2', remove 'stupid2 head2' from it."

I'm trying to query all groups that contain a certain member with..

```
Groups.find({"members": {"firstName": "stupid2", "lastName": "head2"} });
```

But that is returning ALL the groups and not just the ones that match the criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you have to do to "remove" the element of members array with particular first/last name:

```
db.Groups.update( 
     { members : { $elemMatch : {
          firstName : "stupid", 
          lastName: "head"
     } } }, 
     { $pull : { members : {
          firstName : "stupid", 
          lastName: "head"
     } } }
);
```

[$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pull/) is the operator to remove elements from arrays in a document.  [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/) is a way to match an element of an array that has all properties you are specifying.

Comment: yeah, i ended up discovering the $pull method and got it working. i only seem to be update to update via the _id and not other qualifiers. is that a security issue?

Comment: no, it's probably an issue of using incorrect query expression. post as a new question if you can't figure it out?